# Our muscles give us the ability to move our arms but....?

Tags: human-biology, muscles

I have a strange question, but let me tell you something first.

If you think of this carefully, then you realize something, please try this right now:

Contract your muscles only so that your arms move without you doing it. You can't.
The way it happens is that you move your arm (or you do something or whatever you call it), then your muscles contract.
If our muscles weren't there, then we wouldn't be able to move our arms.

**We don't contract our muscles, we move our arms, then our muscles contract automatically. So the muscles contract themselves, but what gives us the ability to make our arms move after deciding when we want to move our arm?**

We can't contract our muscles so that our arm moves, we make that movement, then our muscles contract, but you can't even feel it because it's so light. 
This is hard to explain.

**So what gives us the ability to make our arms move, but not the muscles?** I'm telling you, some people won't even understand, but this is real.

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to edit your question for language and grammar. I tried to keep the revised text as close to your original intent as possible, but if I have made a mistake, feel free to revert the edit or edit it yourself.

Comment: Your brain is responsible for interpreting your spatial "I want to reach that way" and converting it into the proper muscle contractions. You're pretty good at it because you've had a lot of practice, you started working on that skill when you were a baby.

Comment: This question sounds more like philosophy than biology.

Comment: You are trying to connect two neural circuits which are not linked. The muscles act due to discharge from the motor cortex (which gets input from the frontal and prefrontal cortex) which is not directly involved with thought process.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused as to what you are asking. You don't move your arm, like your suggesting, ever. No one does, and no one can. You contract your muscles which happen to move your arm. The movement of the arm is the result of your muscles contracting, not the cause.

How it happens is that your brain sends a signal to your muscles (which you cant feel). The muscles get excited and they contract. The instant your muscle contracts your hand begins to move. In the end your bones are like sticks, and your muscles are the ones that pull the stick in different directions, in order to achieve flexion and extension.

Might i suggest you read up on the musculoskeletal system (http://kidshealth.org/teen/your_body/body_basics/bones_muscles_joints.html) ?

[image: Motor pathway]

Comment: I understand what my question is now, what causes the signals to be sent, how are the signals sent, before the muscles are even contracted.

Comment: If I have satisfactorily answered your question, please click the green tick mark to accept my answer, and if you found it helpful, please do consider upvoting the answer also.

Comment: your answer is not answered im afraid lets see if you can answer the above.

Comment: Can you please be specific as to what exactly you are asking please?

Comment: my question is now,  what causes the brain to send signals. what do we do to cause the brain to send signals, so if I want o lift my arm, then what is it that gives the brain to send signals. what comes after the intention to lift arm, and before the brain sending signals.

Comment: This is quite different to your first question which you asked. Please start a new question for this.